# Using params passed in url with React-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to get a param I'm passing in the URL. This is what I have so far

```
<Route
  path={`/:langCode(${pathPartials.langCodeRegex})/user/password/set?confirmationId=(${pathPartials.confirmationId})`}
  component={SetNewPassword}
/>
```

URL I'm trying

```
http://localhost:3001/en/user/password/set?confirmationId=7029838f-asdz3241-45314dsafc
```

my `pathPartials.confirmationId` regex

```
confirmationId: '[a-z0-9-]*/gmi',
```

The problem is, when I try to do this, I get a 404 instead of my `SetNewPassword` component. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see how the `:langCode(${pathPartials.langCodeRegex})` will end up being `en`, can you elaborate on that? Afaik, anything that *isn't* inside a `${...}` ends up in the string as-is.

Comment: That's a separate part of code, not written by me, which works. The `confirmationId` is the problem. If I remove it, and leave the route as `/:langCode(${pathPartials.langCodeRegex})/user/password/set` the component renders.

Comment: Right, my guess is that you have to make the ID part of the main URL, not state it as GET param: `.../set/:confirmationId(${pathPartials.confirmationId})` Now you can grab it using `const { langCode, confirmationId } = useParams();` in the component. The React Router docs say that the `path` attribute can be anything that'll work with [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0). Or see here: https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-handle-query-params-in-react-router/

Comment: The presented code doesn't seem to work. Also judging by this: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params It should looks something like `/set?confirmationId=:confirmationId(${pathPartials.confirmationId})` Also the `set?` part has to stay like this. Long story short I'm recreating an existing app, and the client wants it to stay exactly like this

Comment: The problem is the way you're stating the regular expression. You need `'[a-z0-9-]+'` or `'[a-z0-9-]{28}'`. That way it'll match, *if* you make ID part of the path. If you keep it as param, the Route path must end in `/set` and you need to grab it from the url: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-url-parameters-bsuyi

Comment: I don't think matching a GET param with `:` will work; if the URLs need to stay like that, just match the path to `.../set` and `exact`, then grab the URL param the usual way and match it manually. (see updated sandbox)

Comment: @ChrisG this almost works. It renders the component, but it doesn't find the `confirmationId`. Also the problem is that the `confirmationId` can be random with length.

Comment: Like I said, since you cannot use the RegEx match stuff of react router anyway due to the requirement of passing `confirmationId` as GET param, you need to parse the URL manually in the component. I showed how to do this in the sandbox, in example.js / SetNewPassword.